# divs scroll over other divs parallax effect with css only

Tags: html, css, parallax

Is the effect on this site http://avadantimo.com/ where you scroll down each section scrolls over the top of the next section possible to replicate using css only? I have conducted much exploration for a solution and could not find a resolution somebody please help my confusion.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Ok I will try to write it in rijndael code but it may take you a while to decipher it

Comment: Paulie I put my code together in a fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/ta48xkyf/

Comment: Hey Paulie bro did did you have a fiddle?

Comment: @ScreamQueen Oh man that got me hysterically laughing. I wish humor never changed. Good job my guy :)

Answer (score 1):

I read this article a while ago and it was pretty neat. It goes into how to do Parallax with CSS and explains what each bit of code is used for.

http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes